# Have filename show on status line in "map! <F12> <ESC>:w<CR>a" rather than Insert

Tags: key-bindings

I use F12 on the Mac (10.11.6)  I've mapped F12 to:

```
 map! ^[[24~ <ESC>:w<CR>a
```

to write my file and return to adding text.

When I use this mapping I see "Insert" on the status line.
Is there a way to delay before the insert begins so the
file name is visible as when one does a manual `<ESC>:w`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible, because as soon as your map finishes, you are left in insert mode so you see the 'showmode' message. There are a couple of alternatives however.

a) Fancy statusline plugins like [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) usually also display the mode, so one does not necessarily need the option 'showmode' anymore: `:set noshowmode`

b) Increase your 'cmdheight' setting to 2: `:set cmdheight=2` so that both messages can be displayed simultaneously.

Please note you can use the keyname instead of the keycode for your mapping. So in your example, you might want to use `imap <f12> <c-\><c-o>:w<cr>` (note instead of using <kbd>esc</kbd> to return from insert mode, I used the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to temporarily switch for one command to normal mode.

Comment: Christian, solution b  is exactly what I needed (simple/effective). FYI: The reason I used the literal string for <F12> is that on my Mac (10.11.6), <F12> simply didn't work.